# Why can't I create VNC sessions?

Tags: linux, vnc

When I type `vncserver`, I get the error below.

Can anyone tell me why am I getting this message? I don't see any problem on `xstartup`.

```
/home/tello/.vnc>vncserver

Couldn't start Xvnc; trying default font path.
Please set correct fontPath in the vncserver script.
Couldn't start Xvnc process.

_XSERVTransSocketCreateListener: failed to bind listener
_XSERVTransSocketUNIXCreateListener: ...SocketCreateListener() failed
_XSERVTransMakeAllCOTSServerListeners: failed to create listener for
unix
_XSERVTransNAMEDOpenServer: Can't open /tmp/.X11-pipe/X21
_XSERVTransOpen: transport open failed for named/spider:21
_XSERVTransMakeAllCOTSServerListeners: failed to open listener for
named

Fatal server error:
Failed to establish all listening sockets
_XSERVTransSocketCreateListener: failed to bind listener
_XSERVTransSocketUNIXCreateListener: ...SocketCreateListener() failed
_XSERVTransMakeAllCOTSServerListeners: failed to create listener for
unix
_XSERVTransNAMEDOpenServer: Can't open /tmp/.X11-pipe/X21
_XSERVTransOpen: transport open failed for named/spider:21
_XSERVTransMakeAllCOTSServerListeners: failed to open listener for
named

Fatal server error:
Failed to establish all listening sockets
```

I didn't see /tmp/.X11-pipe/X21 rather I have /tmp/.X11-pipe/X0 there. Currently I have the following:

```
total 8
drwxrwxr-x   2 root     root          96 May 19 07:56 .
drwxrwxrwt  37 sys      sys         4096 Jun  7 09:52 ..
-rw-rw-rw-   1 root     root           0 May 19 07:56 X0
```

Comment: Please use the same login details as on Stack Overflow here to regain control of your question.

Comment: _XSERVTransNAMEDOpenServer isn't used on linux. I highly doubt this question is tagged correctly. The OP must be on Solaris.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have an access error for `/tmp/.X11-pipe/X21`.  This may be an ownership or privilege for `/tmp`, `/tmp/.X11-pipe`, or `/tmp/.X11-pipe/X21`.  Try using the command `ls -ld` for each of them to see if they exist, and if you have access to them.  If `/tmp/.X11-pipe/X21` exists, you may already have a VNC server on that port, or a failed run may not have cleaned up correctly.